# Combining multiple htaccess rewrite rules into one

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

First, let me say this: I suck at regex and htaccess. I'm trying to make a rule that will properly parse url segments into variables. So far I have this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?query[]=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?query[]=$1&query[]=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?query[]=$1&query[]=$2&query[]=$3 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?query[]=$1&query[]=$2&query[]=$3&query[]=$4 [QSA,L]
```

It works, sort of, but I feel it's longer than it needs to be; and what if I want 5 or 6 or 7 variables? Is there a more condensed way to write this out?

Also, when I spit out the query array, the first element is always index.php. What's up with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `RewriteRule` to convert pathinfo to query parameters, but just enable MultiViews in Apache HTTP Server and use `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` in `index.php` with little help of `explode()`.